Is there a way to have Gismos enabled at startup?
I would like to be able to have "Gizmos" on at the start of Blender, I waste so much time having to turn them on manually every start up.
Is there a addon, or some way to enable Gizmos forever, that I can save in my settings so I do not have to keep doing this? I learned how to use blender in 3.0 and the gizmos were always there and I got used to them, since then, every Blender has not had them.

Gizmos are enabled by default. I might reset to factory settings. How are you turning them on?

As @TheLabCat says they are enabled by default. However, when you have everything set up as you want in a new scene (including all your preferred settings such as render engine, etc.) just use File > Defaults > Save Startup File and you should be good to go.

You can save your startup file:

All settings you set will be saved in it.
